# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[55296,13824]

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, tensor, autoencoder

I'm new to Deep Learning and stackoverflow.

I'm trying to make simple encoder-decoder for my image which is quite big(192*288).
Here's my try:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(55296,))

encoded = Dense(units=13824, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(units=55296, activation='relu')(encoded)
```

But don't know why I'm always getting this error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[55296,13824] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Add]
```

I know that it's because of my tensor size is bigger for my GPU. But it won't work for such simple architecture? I'm using google colab for this and when I change to TPU from GPU it's working but later when I try to fit the model, it'll run out of memory there as well. Please help me with this.

Edit:

I tried to use CNN and here's the architecture:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(192, 288, 1))

encode1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img) 
encode2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(encode1)
encode3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encode2)
encode4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(encode3)
encode5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encode4) 
l = Flatten()(encode5)
l = Dense(3456, activation='relu')(l)
l = Dense(100, activation='relu')(l)

#DECODER
d = Dense(3456, activation='relu')(l)
d = Reshape((48,72,1))(d)
decode1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d) 
decode2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decode1)
decode3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decode2) 
decode4 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decode3)
decode5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decode4) 

model = models.Model(input_img, decode5)
```

But This thing is also running out of memory while training. Can someone guide how can I make better architecture with less weights or I need a better system?

Comment: reduce batch size

Comment: @RajithThennakoon reduce batch size while fitting the model?

Comment: yes.. train on small batches

Comment: @RajithThennakoon but I'm not able to build model model first. While building model only it's giving me this error!

Comment: The weight matrices alone are 6GB. You will either need to *massively* reduce the size of the encoding layer (e.g. with 1000 units it would only be 400MB), or, much better, use a CNN instead.

Comment: @xdurch0 Please check my Edited question. Even This CNN model is running out of memory, can I make some changes there? Any suggestion.